# Google Map api key needed?

Tags: html

Hello: I had a Google map using a kml file created for me. The developer used his api key in the script, so when I use it on my site, the page asks for my site's api key. I am not the developer so how can I obtain an api key?

Comment: guess what is the first result that pops up in google when you search for ["get an api key for google maps"](https://developers.google.com/maps/signup)

Comment: :) that is funny @Banana

Answer (score 1):

API = Application programming interface.
Google will allow your web site to call a Google API many thousand times per day.

If you plan for heavy traffic, you should get an API key from Google. The key is free.

Go to https://console.developers.google.com if you need an API key.

Answer (score 0):

Here : https://developers.google.com/maps/signup

You need to go to DEVELOPRES at GOOGLE and sign up for a key!